# SuiteScript Checkbox Search Results Issues

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

So, I'm running searches on assembly item records and joining with member/component items. Using the 2.x API **N/search** module to get results, for some reason returning the "Is Drop Ship" value always came back as false while the two custom member item checkboxes returned correctly. So, I did a test using the **N/query** module, and the drop ship value came through correctly. Once I built up the full the query with joins and ran it, I then found that those checkboxes on the member items were always coming through as false. I'm completely uncertain as to why this is happening. If I have to run two separate searches to get everything, so be it, but that's obviously not ideal.

Here's simplified code that I'm working with (basically just not including the results processing and renaming the custom checkbox fields). First, the **N/search**, then the **N/query**.

```
require(['N/query', 'N/search'], (query, search) => {
    let itemList = [ /* list of item record internal ids */];
    
    // BEGIN N/search operation
    let itemFilt = [
                ["internalid","anyof",itemList]
        ],
        itemCols = [
                search.createColumn({ name : "itemid" })
            ,   search.createColumn({ name : "isdropshipitem" }) // results always return as false
            ,   search.createColumn({ name : "memberitem" })
            ,   search.createColumn({ name : "memberquantity" })
            ,   search.createColumn({ name : "custitem_checkbox_1" , join : "memberitem" }) // results always return correctly
            ,   search.createColumn({ name : "custitem_checkbox_2" , join : "memberitem" }) // results always return correctly
        ];
    let itemResults = search.create({ type : "assemblyitem" , filters : itemFilt , columns : itemCols }).run().getRange({ start : 0 , end : 1000 });
    // END N/search operation

    itemResults.forEach(res => {
        // result value will always return 'false'
        log.audit({ title : "drop ship checkbox value" , details : res.getValue({ name : "isdropshipitem" }) });
    });

    ///////////////////////
    ///////////////////////
    ///////////////////////
    
    // BEGIN N/query operation || no longer of concern, this issue is solved
    let compQuery = query.create({
            type : query.Type.ITEM
    });
    let filtOne = compQuery.createCondition({
            fieldId : "id"
        ,   operator : query.Operator.ANY_OF
        ,   values : itemList
    });
    compQuery.condition = compQuery.and(filtOne);
    
    let memberJoin = compQuery.joinFrom({
            fieldId : "item"
    //  ,   source : "itemmember" // incorrect join
        ,   source : "member"     // correct join
    });
    let memberItemJoin = memberJoin.joinTo({
            fieldId : "item"
        ,   target : "item"
    });
    
    compQuery.columns = [
            compQuery.createColumn({
                    fieldId : "id"
            })
        ,   compQuery.createColumn({
                    fieldId : "itemid"
            })
        ,   compQuery.createColumn({         // results always return correctly
                    fieldId : "isdropshipitem"
            })
        ,   memberJoin.createColumn({
                    fieldId : "id"
                ,   alias : "memberitem.id"
            })
        ,   memberJoin.createColumn({
                    fieldId : "quantity"
                ,   alias : "memberitem.quantity"
            })
        ,   memberItemJoin.createColumn({
                    fieldId : "itemid"
                ,   alias : "memberitem.itemid"
            })
        ,   memberItemJoin.createColumn({    // results always return as false
                    fieldId : "custitem_checkbox_1"
                ,   alias : "memberitem.custitem_checkbox_1"
            })
        ,   memberItemJoin.createColumn({    // results always return as false
                    fieldId : "custitem_checkbox_2"
                ,   alias : "memberitem.custitem_checkbox_2"
            })
    ];
    
    let compResults = compQuery.run({ }).asMappedResults();
    // END N/query operation
}
```

**EDIT:**

I realized that I made an error in my **query** columns. I discovered that I needed to join to "member" instead of "itemmember". That resolved my issue with the values for the component items in the query. Still not sure why the drop ship checkbox still only returns false in the **search** columns, though.

Also added in a little extra code to highlight where the problem occurs with the results from the **search** module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the value from the member items you'd need:

```js
search.createColumn({ name : "isdropshipitem", join : "memberitem"  })
```

Comment: I was not trying to get that value from the member items, no.